# Graphics card with animal with eyes on it is it haram

Tags: halal-haram, sin, doubts

I wanna get a graphics card for my gaming pc but it has an animal on it with eyes is it haram to buy it as if you were competing with Allah.

Comment: Why should it be haram? Assuming it is do you have an alternative free of such depictions? AFAIK once installed you'll not be able to see the picture.

Comment: It has a dragon on it so it would be fine?

Answer (score -1):

Salaam,
In my opinion, it is not haram at all. As long as you are not committing shirk, worshipping the graphic, there is nothing wrong with it. Remember Allah (swt) made Islam easy for us to follow. This echos what Yusuf alQaradawi once said: "We need diversity in fatawa, a person may impose restriction on himself, but can any modern state afford to do without these?
Muslim Gap